# Is there any difference between 'artfully' and 'artistically'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is there any difference between 'artfully' and 'artistically'? e.g., are there any subtle differences between an 'artfully plated' dish and an 'artistically plated' one?

Comment: Did you look up those words in a dictionary? *Artful* is a synonym for *skillful*, and *artistically* is the adverb form of *artistic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"Artfully"*** is more about skill and adeptness than "art". So, an "artfully plated" dish would look appetizing and attractive, while an "artistically plated" dish of spaghetti might resemble a painting by Jackson Pollock.

Comment: Let's not say things about Jackson Pollock that we can't take back, OK?

Comment: @Robusto - LOL!

Comment: Nobody, including @Robusto has made the obvious point that *artful* carries the strong sense of being clever in a cunning, or underhanded way - as was Dickens'  *Artful Dodger*.

Comment: Why are you singling *me* out?

Comment: Indeed there are two meanings of "skilful" and "cunningly or deceitfully skilful" but I suggest they have to be distinguished by context.